# Ip header help?

Tags: ip, endianness

Why in struct ip is defined like

```
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
    unsigned int ip_hl:4;       /* header length */
    unsigned int ip_v:4;        /* version */
#endif
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
    unsigned int ip_v:4;        /* version */
    unsigned int ip_hl:4;       /* header length */
#endif
```

Little endian and big endianess only affects multibyte values. Why are we storing `ip_hl` before `ip_v`, shouldn't `ip_hl` be transmitted after `ip_v`?

Answer (score 2):

Endianess also affects the way the compiler puts bit-field fields (the ":4" at the end means it's only 4 bits worth of the value) within bytes of the resulting structure.  For big-endian, the bits populate from the most-significant.  For little-endian, the bits populate from the least-significant.